# Вставить div под js скрипт

Tags: javascript, html

Можно ли вставить DIV блок под исполняемый скрипт, если нет за что зацепиться в плане `id` или `class`?

Ситуация такая: я хочу вставить скрипт на сайт в произвольном месте, а там создается `div` блок под `js` в котором моя реклама. Встречал такое, но пока сложно с реализацией...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write

```html
  1
  <script>
    document.write(2);
  </script>
  3
```

Comment: А есть ли решение более деликатное? Нашел такое https://htmlforum.io/topic/21371-javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-documentwrite/ но оно только 1 раз используется, а если 2 скрипта, то на этом все останавливается.

Comment: @VitalyZubarev Так что вам мешает создать див, вставить его через document.write в нужном месте, сохранить его в переменную или массив, а затем обрабатывать дальше как угодно, хоть через ajax запросы отправлять..